# Fake http responses with cucumber

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cucumber, stub

Say, I have a feature in my app that relies on an external API - I provide an interface, which makes calls to my server, and the server, relying on that, makes some calls to some external API and responds something to client. If I wanna write an acceptance test with cucumber for that, how can I stub the calls to that external API, so, e.g. any GET call to `https://www.cool-api.io/foo` would just immediately return some-predefined JSON response with some predefined headers, any POST request to that url would return a response with some predefined status and headers, etc. How do you do it for acceptance tests if you're using cucumber?

Comment: How about using a mocking framework like mockito

Answer (score 1):

We use [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/) or [MockServer](http://www.mock-server.com/) for this. You can implement them to stub API calls.
Also, I'd recommend using a framework like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to generate json from domain objects. The benefits of this are not having to maintain json Strings/docs in your code base, and compile time checks on whether you created valid domain objects in your test.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write my own stub that was able to fake an implementation of the response with the expected content and headers set. If the response object is defined with an interface, then have your hand rolled stub to implement that interface.

Using Mockito for this would probably be to cumbersome in my opinion. Mockito is great, but setting up a complex return value like this may be messy. Hard coding the responses in an implementation of a response interface may be easier.

I would check the actual integration towards the external service using other tooling than Cucumber.